# Prove : $x^{\ln\left(\frac {y}{z}\right)}\cdot y^{\ln\left(\frac {z}{x}\right)}\cdot z^{\ln\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, exponential-function

> Prove : $$x^{\ln\left(\frac {y}{z}\right)}\cdot y^{\ln\left(\frac {z}{x}\right)}\cdot z^{\ln\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)}=1$$

**My Attempt**:
$$\begin{align}\text{L.H.S} &= x^{\ln\left(\frac {y}{z}\right)}\cdot y^{\ln\left(\frac {z}{x}\right)}\cdot z^{\ln\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)}\\&=x^{\ln (y)-\ln(z)} y^{\ln(z)-\ln(x)}.z^{\ln(x)-\ln(y)}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $\ln$, then the expression becomes 
\begin{align*}
\ln(x^{\ln(y/z)}y^{\ln(z/x)}z^{\ln(x/y)})&=(\ln y-\ln z)(\ln x)+(\ln z-\ln x)(\ln y)+(\ln x-\ln y)(\ln z)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
x^{\ln(y/z)}y^{\ln(z/x)}z^{\ln(x/y)}&=e^{\ln(x^{\ln(y/z)}y^{\ln(z/x)}z^{\ln(x/y)})}\\
&=e^{0}\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: user284331, Could you please elaborate? I didn't understand.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... Let us call $E$ the expression to be computed. We know that $E=e^{\ln(E)}$, so we compute $\ln(E)$ first.

Answer (score 2):

Because for positive variables we obtain:  $$x^{\ln \dfrac {y}{z}}y^{\ln \dfrac {z}{x}}z^{\ln \dfrac {x}{y}}=e^{\sum\limits_{cyc}\ln{x}(\ln{y}-\ln{z})}=e^{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\ln{x}\ln{y}-\ln{x}\ln{z}\right)}=e^0=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Taking logarithm, you want to show that $$\ln (x)\ln \left(\frac{y}{z} \right)+\ln (y) \ln \left( \frac{z}{x} \right)+\ln (z) \ln \left( \frac{x}{y}\right)=0 ,$$

which is equivalent to

$$\color{blue}{\ln(x) \ln(y)} \color{red}{- \ln(x)\ln (z)} + \color{green}{\ln(y)\ln(z)}-\color{blue}{\ln(y)\ln(x)}\color{red}{+\ln(z)\ln(x)}\color{green}{-\ln(z)\ln(y)}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

use this logarithm property $a^{ln b}=b^{ln a}$:

$x^{\ln\left(\frac {y}{z}\right)}\cdot y^{\ln\left(\frac {z}{x}\right)}\cdot z^{\ln\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)} = \left(\frac {y}{z}\right)^{\ln x}\cdot \left(\frac {z}{x}\right)^{\ln y}\cdot \left(\frac {x}{y}\right)^{\ln z}=
\frac {y^{\ln x}}{z^{\ln x}}\cdot \frac {z^{\ln y}}{x^{\ln y}}\cdot \frac {x^{\ln z}}{y^{\ln z}}=\frac {y^{\ln x}}{x^{\ln z}}\cdot \frac {z^{\ln y}}{y^{\ln x}}\cdot \frac {x^{\ln z}}{z^{\ln y}}=1$

Answer (score 2):

Let

$x=e^a$ $y=e^b$ $z=e^c$

thus

$$x^{\ln\left(\frac {y}{z}\right)}\cdot y^{\ln\left(\frac {z}{x}\right)}\cdot z^{\ln\left(\frac {x}{y}\right)}=e^{a(b-c)}\cdot e^{a(b-c)} \cdot e^{a(b-c)}=e^{a(b-c)+b(c-a)+c(a-b)}=e^{ab-ac+bc-ba+ca-cb}=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Mutliply all variables by a constant $w$ and notice

$$(wx)^{\log wy/wz}(wy)^{\log wz/wx}(wz)^{\log wx/wy}=w^{\log y/z+\log z/x+\log x/y}x^{\log y/z}y^{\log z/x}z^{\log x/y}=x^{\log y/z}y^{\log z/x}z^{\log x/y}.$$

So WLOG, $x=1$ (by taking $w=1/x$) and you only need to prove

$$y^{\log z}\cdot z^{-\log y}=1,$$ which is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** apply $\ln$ to each side of the equation, and try to simplify it.